# Como crear nuevo array con propiedades de un objeto, si es que cumple condiciones?

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, javascript-objeto

ahi trate de resolverlo pero nose que problema tiene.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te puede funcionar, pero no estoy seguro. Prueba lo de esta forma. Te hablo Jakepy.

```js
function obtenerSoloMayores(estudiantes, nota1, nota2) {
  let newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < estudiantes.length; i++) {
    for (let key in estudiantes) {
      if (
        estudiantes[key].check1 >= nota1 ||
        estudiantes[key].check2 >= nota2
      ) {
        newArr.push(`${estudiantes[key].nombre} ${estudiantes[key].apellido}`);
      }
    }
    break;
  }
  return newArr;
}
```